# py2exe - How to embed external folder to published bundle exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a folder `myFolder` (containing some files and sub folders which are loded in myModule.py) beside the py2exe setup and I want to embed this folder to the final published exe file as a package.

My codes in setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{'script':"myModule.py",'uac_info': "requireAdministrator","icon_resources": [(1, "icon.ico")]}], options={'py2exe':{'bundle_files': 1}},zipfile = None)
```

Is that possible?

Python 2.7.6

Comment: Take a look at this link on data files, I think it's what you want. [Link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files).

Comment: Dear @DasSnipez - Thanks for your answer, my folder contains lots of sub folders and files. Moreover I want to embed that folder to the exe file to have one exe file at the end of publish.

Answer (score 2):

yes above answer is what you want.

```
1.you must add foldernames to your setup file.
2.py2exe will compress and save that folders in one exe file(out come is only one exe)
3. when runnig exe.that folders will recreated automaticaly (py2exe will decompress it and put it back to computr)
```

in above answer there is a link check it ..
in that link there is a function it will help you to add lots of files and folders
without writing one by one.(you need to give foldername only and target)

EXAMPLE :you must write pathname as follows---if you have a file "iam.png" in your computer
----and if you want to put back when installing in "targetpath"

```
("c://targetpath","c.//currentpath/iam.png")
```

this is the tuple you must write in setup file of py2exe

i think your problem was "manyfiles and folders"
    you dont need to write filenames onebyone because there is a function in link..read that ..